# How to add root category to navigation

Tags: magento-1.9

i am a newbie in magento community edition CMS and
i just install a theme and add 2 categories like **mobiles** and **Pen Drives** under the default category.
Also add a root category like namely **cloths** and add two sub categories like **Menu** and  **Woman**

How can i add the cloths root directory to my front end. any body pls help me... front end screen shot attached

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is only one root category per store. Hence, you have to put all the categories which should be shown in the frontend under the Default category (or the root category you configured under `Manage Stores`).

Comment: yes.. Simon you are right..it too difficult

Comment: but how can i put my sub categories to navigation menu as main menu

Comment: I do not understand your question. Every category under the root category will be shown in the frontend.